# Why would you buy large AWS reserved instances?

Tags: reserved-instances

When buying reserved instances on AWS, you can choose what size of instance you want to buy.

But:

- [Each RI has a footprint measured in "normalization factor"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ri-modifying.html#ri-modification-instance-size-footprint)
- When you're billed, it automatically uses whatever instances you have available.
- The pricing *seems* to just be a factor of the normalization factor.

My question is, *why would you ever buy anything but the smallest size*?

For example, if you run a `small` instance in EC2, you might be tempted to buy a `small` reserved instance (3 years, all up front, $229). `small` instances have a normalization factor of 1. Why not buy four `nano` instances instead, which have a normalization factor of 0.25, and cost $228 (a buck cheaper)?

Wouldn't it always be better to purchase the smaller ones so you have the greatest flexibility? Why does Amazon even sell the larger sizes?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I wish I knew what was wrong with the question.

Comment: I assume that even if  people are aware of this possibility they would still simply buy what they (think) they need and won't look for a route to save a single $1 (on their corporate credit card)

Comment: I think you’ve missed the most basic factor in purchasing reserved instances. You HAVE to purchase reserved instances that match the existing type of running EC2 instance. If you have an RI type that matches a running EC2 type then that EC2 instance is billed at the reduced price of the RI. You can not purchase a smaller RI instance and have it apply to a larger EC2 instance. That’s part of the problem with RIs. You are committing to use a specific size EC2 instance for a reduced price over a longer period.

Comment: No, not really. "A Reserved Instance that is purchased for a Region is called a regional Reserved Instance, and provides Availability Zone and instance size flexibility." From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html).

Comment: @Rob, it's not about the dollar savings. It's about the flexibility. Say you buy a there year xlarge reservation to match your xlarge instance, then a week later need to downsize to a large instance. Now, and the end of your three years, you have extra RIs you haven't used and can't sell. Now imagine you bought a bunch of micro RIs for the xlarge instead and you downsize again to large. In this case, you can sell the extra micro RIs on the marketplace. Better! I think nobody here understands this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling vindicated on this one. The AWS Cost Management Reservation Recommendation tool now recommends lots of `micro` reservations when you have larger databases.

For example, we have **zero** `micro` instances, and have a bunch of `xlarge` instances. Instead of recommending that we buy `xlarge` instances, AWS recommends we buy 56 `micro` instances, and even explains:

> To save an estimated $2,894.08 annually, we recommend you purchase db.t3.micro Reserved Instances to cover 28 normalized units per hour of db.t3 family usage to maximize savings over a 1-year term.

[image: Screenshot telling us to buy 56 micro instance]

So if you want the greatest flexibility, AWS recommends it, and now I do too. I haven't heard any explanation why you'd buy anything but the smallest instances in the family you need.